# Ошибка при добавлении класса в папку Policies в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Помогите исправить ошибку. Все ответы на похожие вопросы не помогают. Я создал раздел admin.laws , где можно создавать и удалять записи. Теперь я хочу сделать возможность редактирования. Для этого создаю класс LawPolicy следующего содержания:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\ {User, Law};

class LawPolicy
{
  /**
   * Determine whether the user can manage the law.
   *
   * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
   * @param  \App\Models\Law  $law
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function manage(User $user, Law $law)
  {
      return $user->id === $law->user_id;
  }

  /**
   * Create a new policy instance.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function __construct()
  {
      //
  }
}
```

В класс AuthServiceProvider добавляю в переменную $policies :

```
Law::class => LawPolicy::class,
```

Перехожу на страницу `laws/1/edit` и получаю ошибку:

```
Cannot declare class App\Policies\LawPolicy, because the name is already in use
```

Основу для сайта взял из этого репозитория: https://github.com/bestmomo/laravel5-5-example

Точно такие шаги я совсем недавно проделал для другого раздела. А что с этим неправильно я не понимаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Краш был по причине того, что я по ошибке скопировал содержимого LawPolicy в файл edit.blade.php . Поэтому Laravel пытался импортировать повторно класс с точно таким же именем и namespace. Странно, что я не нашёл это при помощи grep. Подсказка тем, кто нагуглит этот вопрос, будьте внимательнее и ищите класс-дублёр несколькими способами.